# Can not create client library.Not able to add methods to endpoint

Tags: android, google-app-engine, illegalargumentexception

Not able to generate client library after adding the following method to the endpoint:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "checkNumberPresent")
public List<Entity> checkNumberPresent(@Named("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber){
    List<Entity> result;
    result=ContactSearchHelper.ifNumberExists(phoneNumber);
    return result;

}
```

The method is to query the datastore if a number exists.However, while trying to generate client library,following error message is displayed.
[image]

Where am I getting wrong?Thanks.

My Entity Class code:

```
@Entity
public class UserInfo {

@Id
private String userRegistrationID;
private String userPhoneNumber;
private long timestamp;

public String getUserRegistrationID() {
  return userRegistrationID;
}

public String getUserPhoneNumber() {
  return this.userPhoneNumber;
}

public void setUserRegistrationID(String userRegistrationID) {
  this.userRegistrationID = userRegistrationID;
}

public void setUserPhoneNumber(String userPhoneNumber) {
 this.userPhoneNumber = userPhoneNumber;
}
public void setRegisteredAppVersion(String registeredAppVersion) {
    this.registeredAppVersion = registeredAppVersion;
}
public String getRegisteredAppVersion() {
    return registeredAppVersion;
}

public long getTimestamp() {
  return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
 this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
}
```

And the code for querying datastore to retrieve data is:

```
  public class ContactSearchHelper {

  //Query datastore to retrieve entity with the phoneNumber field equal to the passed phoneNumber
  public static List<Entity> ifNumberExists(String phoneNumber){

    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Filter numberFilter =new FilterPredicate("userPhoneNumber",FilterOperator.EQUAL,phoneNumber);

    // Use class Query to assemble a query
            Query q = new Query("UserInfo").setFilter(numberFilter);
            // Use PreparedQuery interface to retrieve results
            PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
            int numberOfEntities=pq.countEntities(null);

            if(numberOfEntities>0){
                List<Entity> retrievedList=pq.asList(null);
                return retrievedList;
            }else{
                return null;
            }


}

   }
  }
```

I hope I am able to provide sufficient codes to explain the issue.Thanks.

Comment: I had exactly the same error.  Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: @Dmytriy , Not able to resolve it..Have you found any similar questions?

Comment: as far as I know you cannot return List<Entity> from your API. Entity object is not POJO. Try to replace Entity to your own declared class with the same properties and getters/setters for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same error. In my case the problem was that I have added custom method getEntity to my class that is wrapped into API. This method was intended to cast my class to Entity objects (as I did not use JDO/JPA). Something like:

```
public class MyUser {


    private String userCookie;
    public String getUserCookie() {
        return userCookie;
    }

    public void setUserCookie(String userCookie) {
        this.userCookie = userCookie;
    }

    ...

    public Entity getEntity(){
        Entity e = new Entity("MyUser");
        e.setProperty("userCookie", this.getUserCookie());

        ...

        return e;
    }

}
```

(Now I understand that it was not good architecture). And in my API get method I wrote something like:

```
@Api(name = "user")
public class UserApi {

    @ApiMethod(name = "users.insert")
    public void insert(MyUser user) {
        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        e = user.getEntity();
        datastore.put(e);

    }
}
```

It was a mistake to start method name with getXYZ prefix when one do not have XYZ property in the class which is expected to be POJO (and that is a case in cloud endpoints). I just renamed getEntity method to convertToEntity and everything started working. So, check if you classes do not have custom getters. Getters and setters should be only for properties declared in the class.

Comment: Thankyou.I am still not able to spot the problem in my codes.but I have found that if I change return type of the method to void , the client library is generated.But that will not serve my purpose.Still trying...

Comment: @pratim What is your current return type? Can you post some code for me to help you?

Comment: I have inserted some codes in my question.Please check if that explains my problem well. Thankyou.

Comment: @pratim, first of all try to delete setRegisteredAppVersion and  getRegisteredAppVersion methods. Second, did you annotate your API class ContactSearchHelper? I have doubts that return type of the method: public static List<Entity> ifNumberExists is Entity, I think it should be UserInfo.

Comment: I followed what you suggested and am now able to generate client library. The return type of List<Entity> is changed to List<UserInfo>.I am yet to run the program and test.But I couldnt understand why you said to delete two methods-setRegisteredAppVersion and getRegisteredAppVersion from entity class.And ContactSearchHelper is a class in the backend project. It's methods will not be called directly from the client app classes but from the endpoint class only. So, is it necessary to annotate this class?